# Add unity into React native expo

Tags: react-native

I would like to add unity into my react native expo app. Since I searched I don't find anything helpful for me and related to my requirement. Is there any Sample/Reference code available for Unity Integration with React native?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

ive been in the same place. so currently theres no way to directly communicate it with Unity. But you can always communicate with native android/ios and that in turn communicates with unity. worked with that, and it works pretty well. so your native side should launch the game rather than react native directly starting it.

Basically call a native method in android side from react native --> that in turn starts / calls the unity module .

[check this once](https://pronteff.com/unity-integration-in-react-native/)

Hope this helps. otherwise please connect with me

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Actually I forgot to add a note in the question. My webGL build folder contains .unityweb and .json files in it. I have to import this into my project. Is there any possible way to include this?

Comment: you can check this thread once

Comment: @GauravRoy Hey! I have the same issue and do you know any libraries help with it? I know react-unity-webgl but it is only for web but I want to build native apps. I saw the link you put above and it is same as this old package.https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view